# Why the validation error messages don't display

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I was about to update my existing data in sql.
I am updating the data using ajax with validation error

ajax validation works on my account creation and change password

below are my ajax code

```
$('#form-battery-update').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var me = $(this);

// perform ajax
$.ajax({
// url: me.attr('action'),
url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>msasset/update_battery_form_validation',
type: 'post',
data: me.serialize(),
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response) {
if (response.success == true) {
  // if success we would show message
  // and also remove the error class
  $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
    ' UPS Battery has been created' +
    '</div>');
  $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
          .removeClass('has-success');
  $('.text-danger').remove();

  // reset the form
  me[0].reset();

  // close the message after seconds
  $('.alert-success').delay(500).show(10, function() {
    $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
      $(this).remove();

    });
  })
}

else {
  $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
    var element = $('#' + key);

    element.closest('div.form-group')
    .removeClass('has-error')
    .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
    .find('.text-danger')
    .remove();
    element.after(value);
  });
}
}
});
});
```

below are my code from my views folder

```
<div class="card-body p-0">

        <?php echo form_open("msasset/update_battery_form_validation", array("id" => "form-battery-update", "class" => "form-horizontal")) ?>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block bg-register-image"></div>
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="p-5">
              <div class="text-center">

                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4"><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
                  <div id="the-message"></div>
              </div>
              <?php
           if(isset($fetch_single_battery))
           {
                foreach($fetch_single_battery->result() as $row)
                {
           ?>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Battery SerialNumber</label> </br>
                <p class="form-control"> <?php  echo $row->SerialNumber; ?></p>

           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>PO Number</label> </br>
                <input type="text" name="PONumber" value="<?php echo $row->PONumber; ?>" class="form-control"/>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ticket</label>
                <input type="text" name="ticketid" value="<?php echo $row->TicketNumber; ?>" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("ticketid"); ?></span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Data Port</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="select_port">
                    <option class="form-control" selected><?php echo $row->DataPort; ?></option>
                  <?php foreach ($GetPortLocation as $Port) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $Port['DataPort']; ?>"><?php echo $Port['DataPort']; ?></option>
                <?php   } ?>
                </select>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("select_port"); ?></span>
                      <span class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>UPS Asset Tag</label>
                <input type="text" name="ups_asset_tag" value="<?php echo $row->UPS_AssetTag; ?>" class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger"></span>

           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date Installed</label>
                <input type="date" name="date_installed" value="<?php echo $row->DateInstalled; ?>"  class="form-control" />
                <span class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Status</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="select_status">
                <option class="form-control" selected><?php echo $row->Status; ?></option>
                <?php foreach($get_AssetStatus as $AssetStatus){?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $AssetStatus['AssetStatus']; ?>"><?php echo $AssetStatus['AssetStatus']; ?></option>
                  <?php }  ?>
                </select>

           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $row->ID; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" />
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
           </div>
           <?php
                }
           }

           ?>
          </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

below codes from my controller

```
function update_battery_form_validation()
    {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('PONumber','po number','required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('ticketid','ticket id','required');



        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {

            $this->load->model('assets_model');
            $data  = array(
                'PONumber' => $this->input->post('PONumber'),
                'TicketNumber' => $this->input->post('ticketid'),
                'DataPort' => $this->input->post('select_port'),
                'UPS_AssetTag' => $this->input->post('ups_asset_tag'),
                'DateInstalled' => $this->input->post('date_installed'),
                'Status' => $this->input->post('select_status'),
                'PerformedBy' => $this->session->userdata('user_name')
            );
            if($this->input->post('update'))
            {
                $this->assets_model->update_battery($data,$this->input->post('hidden_id'));
                $this->session->set_flashdata('batteries_updated','New battery has been updated successfully');
                redirect('msasset/ups_batteries');
            }
        }
        else
        {
          // echo  validation_errors();
          foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
          {
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
          }

        }
                echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

I was expecting that every time there is an empty fields it should give me an a this fields required messages and also if all the fields fill with data it also does not load the page or save the data

Comment: They aren't displaying because you are using ajax and `form_error` code in your view fields won't refresh because the page isn't refreshing. form error in the view used the way you are using it is for a traditional, non ajax form. You assign validation errors to a json_encoded array and you can use that populate your validation errors using jquery. further, your controller redirects on success (which it should never), and never sets response.success to true.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for this response,

I've tried setting response.success on my ajax code it shows success message.
however, the data has never been updated.

also, it still don't show empty fields required.

I really apologize I am still a newbie in doing this and still learning the best way

Comment: yea, also you have another issue. you have a foreach in the form, and your field names aren't arrays. as it is, if you have more than 1 result you'll have multiples of each field name, which isn't a problem if you declare the field name as `name=somefield[]` however as it is now the last row will be the only data sent since each `somefield` overrides the previous. names must be unique (w3c). and if you went with arrays submitting multiple rows at the same time update or not requires a different backend approach that is outside the scope of the comments to explain.

Comment: as you said you are new, and frankly there are too many issues for me the address in any way that would make sense. i would suggest getting the form to work properly without ajax, maybe only have the form with 1 row/id so you don't have to deal with the complexity arrays introduce. then branch out in to ajax implementations if you feel your code requires it.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for this hints and suggestion,

I will try to work things out based on your advised.

I will update this thread when it works out.